# Is there a fill parent for Text Size?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a sign (the ones that drivers use at the airport to find someone "Mr Smith") and I wanted the sign to have the largest Font size possible, (its for a tablet), I could write a function to change the size depending on the length of the Text but is there a way of doing natively/better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible way is to create a custom view that draws the text in `onDraw()`. When drawing the text (with one of [`Canvas.drawText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)) you will have to provide a Paint, and that would let you know the precise length of text, not just length of string (see [`Paint.measureText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29)).

This way you would have plenty of ways to calculate and redistribute the space (and it would totally rely on you how).

One way I can think of is calculating the length for a huge font size and then using the h/w ratio to see if I want to fill the screen in width or height.